# Not able to search for $ in datadog logs

Tags: lucene, datadog

I am searching for the occurrence of character `$` in a log file on datadog log explorer which uses lucene syntax. It's pretty similar to kibana. I have logged a string for testing `Testing $ pattern datadog` but when I search for `$` it doesn't show any results. On searching for `Testing` I get `Testing $ pattern datadog` in response. Please tell me how can list the occurrences of `$` any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to setup in `logs > configuration > pipelines` a [category processor](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/processing/processors/?tab=ui#category-processor) to add a new attribute that could be made searchable.

[image: category processor example]

---

*edit: 19th Nov 2019*

Step 1:

Add grok parser to extract sign:

rule: `detect_dollar .*%{regex("[$]+"):dollarSign}.*`
[image]

Step 2:

Then you can setup a category processor as indicated above. This could look for the attribute `@dollarSign:$` and set the attribute `hasDollarSign` to True and set it to false otherwise.

[image]

Step 3:

Create a facet on `dollarSign` attribute. Following logs can then be searched for.

For logs with no `$`

```
-@dollarSign:$
```

For logs with `$`

```
@dollarSign:$
```

You can do the same with the `hasDollarSign` attribute and set it as a facet.

Comment: How does this help? I'm not able to search for "$"

Comment: You are not able to search for it directly in the Log Explorer but you can configure a pipeline that would enrich your log with an attribute "hasDollarSign" that you can set to True or False based on the incoming message. I'll edit the answer above to make it clearer.